# How to add font size Drop Down in Rad Editor?

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a rad editor where i need to add font size drop down which has values like 11px, 12px etc.
How do I achieve this in aspx page?

Comment: Please respond it's urgent. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have added the font size for the rad editor but it is taking values 1,2, 3...7. I have not defined these values it is taking by default . This is the line of code i have added in aspx page: <telerik:EditorTool Name="FontSize" ShortCut="CTRL+SHIFT+P" /> How can i add my own defined values to the font size dropdown list. Please suggest